# Non-clumsy way to specify column for `filter()` in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I want to read a dataframe and it based on condition "private == 1" (using spark 2.1).  I know I can do it in two lines, something like

```
 tmp = spark.read.parquet(if_name)
 data = tmp.filter(tmp.private == 1)
```

However, in sparkR I can do this as one-liner without the temporary `tmp` dataframe like

```
data = read.parquet(if_name) %>% filter(column("private") == 1)
```

Is there a way to achieve the same in pyspark (function `[Cc]olumn` seems to be undefined)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a column:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col
spark.read.parquet(if_name).filter(col("private") == 1)
```